# How can i bindLabel with multiple values in Angular?

Tags: angular

i need to bind multiple values on bindLabel tag in ng-select on Angular.

How can i do that?

My HTML code:

```
<div [formGroup]="adressFormGroup">
  <ng-select class="form-control" id="adress" [appendTo]="'body'"
    name="adress" 
    [items]="adress"
    [formControl]="adressControl" 
    bindValue="id" 
    bindLabel="adress"
    placeholder="Select Adress" 
    onkeydown="return false" 
    (change)="onChangeAdress($event);"
    [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': adressControl.invalid &&  (adressControl.dirty || adressControl.touched)}">
   <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item">
      <span style="float: left;">{{item.adressType}} {{item.adress}} {{item.number}} {{item.city}}</span> <br/>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-select>
  <small *ngIf="adressControl.invalid &&  (adressControl.dirty || adressControl.touched)" class="validation-imput">{{ formErrors.adress}}</small>
</div>
```

Item is a object that contains all values of adress.

When i select a combo item display:

Avenue NE 153 ST 1959 North Miami

But after click, display NE 153 ST only.

Many Thanks

Comment: Do you have a reproducible example after trying something from [the documentation](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/bindings) (that is assuming that's the correct library you're using)?

Answer (score 0):

You can define one more `ng-template` similar to the one defined for displaying options and use `ng-label-tmp` directive as:

```html
<ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item">
   <span style="float: left;">{{item.adressType}} {{item.adress}} {{item.number}} {{item.city}}</span> <br/>
</ng-template>
```